# I have to download some Palette items Android Studio 3.5 again & again

Tags: android, android-studio

( I'm a Beginner in android development  )
Whenever i open a new project in android studio (or even the existing ones) In Palette Box some items have a download icon in front of them, and I have to download these items whenever i open a new project in android studio ,to use them.
This is very annoying for me, like if the internet is not available then i can't have the access to use these items.
So, is there any way so that i can download them permanently and use them even when there is no internet available.

[image: Here is the picture of these items]

I have reinstall the android studio 3.5 but still the problems remains the same.

Comment: Have you tried Invalidating caches\ restart...?